# Xamarin.essentials FilePicker copies selected external file to cache folder

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

For the last 2 weeks I've been successfully converting a WPF application to a Xamarin.forms android app. Everything works as intended except for 1 thing. I've been searching the web for a few days for a solution but I can't find a working solution.
This is my current setup:

- Xamarin.Froms android app
- Target android version: Android 10.0
- Minimum android version: Android 7.0
- Xamarin.Essentials version: 1.6.0
- READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
- WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

---

My app should be able to open a selected file, using the Xamarin.Essientials FilePicker, Do some stuff and save the File again to the same path. The file selection is handled in the following code:

```
        var pickresult = await FilePicker.PickAsync();

        if (pickresult != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await pickresult.OpenReadAsync();
                var reader = new StreamReader(result);
                var jsonstring = reader.ReadToEnd();
                ConfigData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectData>(jsonstring);
                PLC_Data.ProjectLoaded = true;
                L_LoadedProject.Text = pickresult.FileName;

                ProjectData.Filepath = pickresult.FullPath;

                reader.Close();
                result.Close();

                //Load login page
                B_Next.IsEnabled = true;
            }
```

This is where the problem occurs. Let me clearify what happens step by step:

- The FilePicker opens a File picking window.
- I navigate to my preferred file in the "download" folder, could be any folder.
- The file is read and converted to an object
- The file path is saved

when i check the filepath i get the following string:

> "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.FAIS.motorconfigapp/cache/2203693cc04e0be7f4f024d5f9499e13/303bc84665374139b6303c03255e9018/config1.json"

So the FilePicker copies the "External" file to the App cache folder and returns the filepath from the Apps cache folder. When i check this folder there is indeed a copy of my selected file inside it. Reading from and writing to this file works as it should.

Now the actual question:
Why does the FilePicker copy my selected file to his cache folder and how can i prevent it?
The user should be able to select a file from anywere on the device and find the updated file in the same location.

I've checked all my settings and in my opinion everyting should be correct so i don't get why a copy is created. Does anyone have an idea?
If you need more settings, pictures, versions please ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is going to depend upon the Android API level, if the OS returns a full `file://` file path or if the URI returned is found in the content provider, then the file can be used in place, otherwise Essentials creates a cached copy.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly I can't control what the OS returns? Then I'll just save the file to a fixed folder and the user will need to look there. The app is for internal company use so its not the end of the world I guess  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can't control what the OS returns while you can check the Android API level at run time and then you can know what is returning,

Comment: It is really about how Essentials handles (or does not handle) the newer Android file sandboxing and also how security is granted on a temp. basis (based upon active Activity), but to make it fit a standard model Essentials creates a copy before losing the  OS permission to the file. If coding this directly in Xamarin.Android you could handle this "issue" correctly.